# Gaussian process for hyperparameter search

Tags: gaussian-process

I read from various sources that Gaussian process (GP) is a promising way to do hyperparameter search/optimization for ML/DL model. However, GP itself also has hyperparameters such as length-scale, the signal variance and the noise variance. So how is GP a valid way of doing hyperparameter search if itself also needs hyperparameter search (same problem still persists)?

Comment: The hyperparameters of GP can be found in a few seconds when the sample size isn't too big (say less than a hundred or so). If fitting your ML model at one hyperparameter setting takes say 1 hour, the GP problem is trivial in comparison to the hyperparameter problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you also recommend some reference materials on how to do hyperparameter tuning for GP?